# Using panel info instead of infowindow with CartoDB?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am using CartoDB API to develop a map viewer and I would like to get the information from featureClick into a content panel instead of the typical infowindow. Is there any method to do it directly? I mean, I have seen some examples about how to include a template dinamically but it is always displayed as an infowindow popup. Could the template be linked to another html element and disable infowindow popup?

I know that layer has the attributes and values (also using layer interactivity fields) but I would like to know if there is a method which can be used as similar as the template-infowindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty easy to get the data to any DOM element you specify.

If you look at the definition of [events on layers](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#events), you'll see that the requested data is returned as a callback object:

```
layer.on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
    console.log("mouse over polygon with data: " + data);
});
```

If you specify in your HTML document a div element, say `<div id="info"></div>`, you can include this code to make the clicked data appear in the `div` element:

```
layer.on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data, subLayerIndex) {
    $("#info").html("<h4>Name</h4><p>" + data.name + "</p>");
});
```

Make sure you enable interactivity using `sublayer.setInteraction(true)` and `sublayer.setInteractivity('column1, column2, ...')` to ensure that the data is associated with an interaction. See their method references [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayersetinteractiontrue) and [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayersetinteractivitycartodbid-name-).

If you want to disable the template infowindows, you do so in the CartoDB Editor by [deselecting all the fields](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#info-windows) if you are using a viz.json file. If you are making a map by [defining dynamic layers](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#creating-visualizations-at-runtime), infowindows are disabled by default.

Here's a [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/ohasselblad/d9b65186664268d6dec4) that uses what was discussed above.